# How to add an ajax search function in rails.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails .I want to add ajax live search function in my rails application.i have already used many codes but those are not working .when I use pagination method i had the follwing error  undefined local variable or method `sort_column' for #
so, how to add an ajax  live search in rails application??
Is it possible to use the jquery with ajax.?

Comment: When you say "Ajax Search", I am presuming you mean [Livesearch](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/live-search/) (like Facebook & similar)?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial by ryan is awesome to give a start

http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax